# .NET char serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, char

This line of XML I created sometime ago

```
  <char>48</char>
```

is deserialised to '0'.  The comment in my XML file indicates this is the decimal representation of a character.  However this [link http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) says '0' = dec 16.

Anyone have any idea why 48 is translated to an '0'?   Probably a long day and I will figure it out tommorrow but any insight will be appreciated, thanks.

TIA>

Comment: That table says 'a' is dec 97, not dec 16.  And how does that relate to any other part of the question?

Comment: That was a typo and I have corrected.  I was reading the table wrong.  '0' is dec 48.  Was indeed a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal 48 through 57 are the characters '0' through '9'.

Decimal 0 through 31 are [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).  Decimal 26 is the [Substitute character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).  None of these characters are printable which may explain the odd result.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to respond.